# Run django in docker with pycharm

Tags: django, docker, pycharm

I am trying to use PyCharm for remote debugging in my django project. I have created a Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
RUN python manage.py makemigrations
RUN python manage.py migrate

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

And successfully used `docker build -t dockering .` to create image. I can view it:

```
$  docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                           PORTS                                            NAMES
58e102ea8aaf        dockering:1.0                                "python -u /opt/.p..."   11 minutes ago      Created                                                                           peaceful_babbage
b10984d7f177        9adf577a7852                                 "python manage.py ..."   12 minutes ago      Exited (137) 8 minutes ago
```

And run it with `docker run -p 8000:8000` and enter successfully my localhost:8000. When I try to do this in PyCharm however, it seems to bee unable to find correct image.

I have set up proper interpreter in settings:

[image: Settings]

And set up command:

[image: Command]

However, when I try to run it I have:

> 890e40a906dd:python -u /opt/project/manage.py runserver localhost:8000
>   Performing system checks...
>
> System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
>
> You have 13 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly
>   until you apply the migrations for app(s): admin, auth, contenttypes,
>   sessions. Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them. August 01,
>   2017 - 08:47:56 Django version 1.11, using settings
>   'dockering.settings' Starting development server at
>   http://localhost:8000/ Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

And as you can imagine entering localhost:8000 tells me the website does not work. What have I missed?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem because my `manage.py runserver` was pointing to  `0.0.0.0:8000` while Django configuration, in PyCharm, pointed to `localhost`. When I set them all to `0.0.0.0:8000` it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I was running into this too. In the "run/debug configuration" you need to set the "host" to 0. That is the host that will be injected into the "runserver" command.

[image]